# How to repair hard disk

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have Buffalo HD-PCTU3 : MINISTATION™ USB 3.0 hard disk.
It was working fine but now its now performing well.
It sometimes shows in My computer but sometimes doesn't show. Reading content from hard disk is difficult. It is not completely not working.
I think the problem is with bad sector. Windows scan for bad sector doesn't help.

Is there any method or software to repair this type of problem?

Comment: If it has a bad sector then you can't "repair" it.  If you care about the data on the drive you should replace the drive and transfer the data over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try another usb/firewire/thunderbolt adapter for your HDD. If it won't solve the problem check the surface of your HDD with special software (on OS X: Tech Tool Pro, for example).

Comment: +1 agree, I would suspect the cable or enclosure first, then work from there